# How do I list and view users' permissions with gcloud?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-platform

If I go to "IAM & admin" in the google cloud console and select the "IAM" tab on the left I see a list of users (username@mydomain).

How do I list these users with gcloud? And how do I see what access a user has been given with gcloud?

I have not been able to find out how to do this in the terrible google docs.

Answer (score 22):

<s>I believe you'll find some answers on [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746358/how-do-i-list-all-iam-users-for-my-google-cloud-project). Good luck! The docs took me a bit to grok, too. Usually assembling search engine strings like `gcloud [title of console tool i was trying to find a CLI version of]` seems to work.</s>

EDIT, 3 years later!

The command you're looking for is [get-iam-policy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy):

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <project-id>

# Example:
gcloud projects get-iam-policy my-fancy-project
```

This is assuming, of course, that the IAM permissions are assigned to the users at the *project* level. You may also want to use [get-ancestors-iam-policy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-ancestors-iam-policy), which includes project AND inherited roles from the folder and org levels:

```
gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy <project-id>

# Example:
gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy my-fancy-project
```

EDIT 2: Props to @jelle-den-burger for following up about the `get-ancestors-iam-policy` command, added in v311.0.0 in Sept 2020.

Comment: Exactly what I'm searching for :-) Thanks!

Comment: Small detail: this does not include permissions inherited from the folder & organization level. So the IAM user interface in Google Cloud Console and whatever `gcloud` returns might not be the same.

Comment: update: they thought about it. See my answer below.

Comment: I think this command lists the members and the roles, not my individual permissions

Answer (score 8):

The initial question was **asking about permissions**, but I can only see **answers listing roles** and **there is a difference between roles and permissions**. For the sake of future visitors (like me :) ) I will add an additional command.

### Explanation of the difference:

**Permissions** in GCP are allowing access to the specific type of the **resource** and **role** is **a group of such permissions**.
e.g. Editor role has all the permissions that Viewer role has and also additional ones allowing to manage networking, instances,etc.

`compute.instances.create` is a permission allowing to create an instance.
`roles/Editor` is a role containing this permission. Assigning role gives a permission for the user to the resource.

### Solution:

Listing roles can be done by commands mentioned by **Jelle den Burger** or **ingernet** ( `gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy <project-id>` ), but if you want to know more specifically what kind of permissions does the user have, you need to dig deeper. With my short research, I was able to find only this command describing what permissions does a role contain:

`gcloud iam roles describe [ROLE]`

example `gcloud iam roles describe roles/spanner.databaseAdmin`

So you would have to write a short shell script to connect those two commands, first one listing user roles, second one listing permissions of the roles. The outcome will be a list of **permissions** user has.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is correct and you do indeed get the permissions. But when you look into the Google Cloud Console online, there might be many more permissions applied, coming from the Folder & Organizations level.

Luckily Google thought about this and they also offer a `get-ancestors-iam-policy` command. You use it as such:

```
gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy <project-id>

# Example:
gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy my-fancy-project
```

It will returns all permissions: on the **Project**, **Folder**, and **Organization** level, just as you would in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Looks like they added that command in [Sept 2020](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_resource_manager_3), a few months after my update to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is very helpful if you want to know which permissions a particular entity has in a project policy without reading what can be a large document.

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy my-fancy-project --format=json | jq '.bindings[] | select(.members[] | contains("serviceAccount:theServiceAccount")) | .role'`

1. Display the project IAM Policy as JSON: `gcloud projects get-iam-policy my-fancy-project --format=json`
2. Pipe it into `jq`.
3. For all bindings in the document `.bindings[]`
4. Select the binding if the entity exists in the members list `select(.members[] | contains("serviceAccount:theServiceAccount"))`
5. extract the binding's role: `.role`

---

Several answers here also explain the difference between a project's policy and how permissions are granted from ancestors such as folders and orgs. You should read those, too!

The query for policies including ancestors would be

`gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy my-fancy-project --format=json | jq '.[].policy.bindings[] | select(.members[] | contains("serviceAccount:theServiceAccount")) | .role'`

Answer (score 0):

I come up with 2 bash functions based on @Mr.TK's answer, to list permissions based on roles and print only that specific role. I don't have ancestors here so please feel free to query ancestors' permissions according to other answers.

```bash
gcloud-get-roles() {
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy <your-fancy-project> | grep "role:" | awk '{print $2}'
}

gcloud-list-permissions() {
    allPerm=
    if [ -z "$@" ]; then
        echo "Listing all permissions"
        allPerm=true
    else 
        echo "Listing permissions containing $@"
    fi
    while IFS= read -a role; 
    do
        if [[ "$role" =~ ^projects/.* ]] || [[ "$role" =~ ^organizations/.* ]]; then
            echo "Wrong role: $role, should not start with 'projects/' or 'organizations/"
            continue
        fi
        if [ "$allPerm" == "true" ]; then
            echo "Role: $role"
            gcloud iam roles describe "$role" | grep -E "^- "
        else 
            if gcloud iam roles describe "$role" | grep "$@" > /dev/null; then
                echo "Role: $role"
                gcloud iam roles describe "$role" | grep "$@"
            fi
        fi
    done <<< "$(gcloud-get-roles)"
}
```

Example output with arguments(you can of course use without, which will list all permissions; you can then grep in that)

```bash
$ gcloud-list-permissions iap
Listing permissions containing iap
Wrong role: projects/xxx, should not start with 'projects/' or 'organizations/
Role: roles/editor
- iap.projects.getSettings
- iap.projects.updateSettings
- iap.tunnelDestGroups.create
- iap.tunnelDestGroups.delete
- iap.tunnelDestGroups.get
- iap.tunnelDestGroups.list
- iap.tunnelDestGroups.update
- iap.web.getSettings
- iap.web.updateSettings
...
```

It will take a while to get results as roles are passed one by one to the 2nd function, but at least we save manual work.