# How to get the list of all the Members in IAM in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-iam

I have provided access to so many user in my GCP account using IAM > ADD Member. I want to get the list of all the members present in IAM using gcloud CLI. I have not created any group for them, just simply added their mail id's and granted them permission. 
Is there any way to get the list of all the members using cloud shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the right access privileges this command on cloud shell should give you the list of users.
`gcloud projects get-iam-policy <name of the project>`

Comment: This will not show principals who are granted privileges by dint of their organizational roles, as indicated in [@ingernet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47028896/148680).