# Batch method for getIamPolicy from Google CRM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-resource-manager

In my work, I need to fetch all of the IAM policies for each of the GCP projects we manage (several thousand projects as it stands today).

When I use [`projects.getIamPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/getIamPolicy), I am seeing periodic `429` responses as we're exceeding the quota limit.

However, I cannot find a means in which to make a batch request to Google, or do something like fetch policies for *all* projects within a given GCP *folder*.

Aside from simply adding retries/backoff to the API calls or increasing the quota limit, is there a more intelligent way to get all the IAM policy information for *many* projects at once?

So far, I have tried consulting the Google CRM API documentation, in which I see a method for fetching folder IAM policies ([`folders.getIamPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/folders/getIamPolicy)) but not a batch request or folder request to get project-level data.

Additionally, I am making changes to request a higher quota limit and add retries, though I would prefer to refactor this into a more sensible design (instead of implementing bandaid solutions).

Answer (score 0):

There might be many more permissions applied, coming from the Folder & Organizations level.
    gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy <project-id>
    
    # Example: gcloud projects get-ancestors-iam-policy my-fancy-project
You can check the reference from this [post][1] by Jelle den Burger

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006116/how-do-i-list-and-view-users-permissions-with-gcloud