# What are my privileges in a given GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

There are several ways my user can get privileges in a Google Cloud Platform project. Direct role and privilege assignment, act as service accounts, different group membership.

So given a GCP project, how can I list the active privileges for my user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJ \
  --flatten="bindings[].members" \
  --format='table(bindings.role)' \
  --filter="bindings.members:user:$USER"
```

`USER` is like email (*me@org.com*), `PROJ` is like *project-654321*.

**UPDATE** To search across **all resources**:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --query=policy:$EMAIL
```

Comment: Your example will show IAM Role bindings at the **project** resource, but not at other resources.

Comment: I'm not aware of other resources. If something is billable I assume it is attached to a project, what kind of resources are there besides those that under the project?

Comment: You are confusing resources that belong to projects and resources that support IAM bindings. Your command only shows IAM bindings for a project, not for individual resources. Cloud Run, KMS, Cloud Storage, etc also support IAM bindings. In other words, I can bind an IAM role to KMS yet the user has no IAM roles bound to the project.

Comment: Right! Like `gcloud organizations get-iam-policy $ORG` or `gcloud compute instances get-iam-policy $INST`.

Comment: Correct. Those commands show the IAM bindings for those resource types.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, in GCP, they are called "[Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#permissions_and_roles)". For ease of use, those permissions are grouped in "Roles".

Each user can have different roles in your project. To get a full list of the accounts having each role in a project, you can use the [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/) to [get the IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy).

Long story short, make sure that `gcurl` is properly configured and just run the following command, filtering the output according to your needs:

```
curl -XPOST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$(gcloud config get-value project):getIamPolicy -d'{}' -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H'content-type:application/json'
```

Comment: True, but it doesn't solve the original use case. Say I want to know if my user has `bigquery.table.update`. I may get that transitively through an act as some service account, and I may not know all the groups I'm member of. 

I can't find a way to just list the permissions my user has.

Comment: If you know the permission you want to check, you can call the testIamPermission of the same API. You'll have to enable the proper oauth flow (three legged oauth) to properly call this endpoint as the end user.

Comment: easier still: `gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT `
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44749561/1778702